# How to reuse Meteor business logic in mobile app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, meteor, ddp

We are a young startup that choose Meteor against traditional MEAN stack to develop a realtime web application.

One important thing for us is to develop a native mobile apps in near future (android, iOS).

After some research we discovered that there are native DDP clients for android and ios, but we are unsure how to share business logic between web and mobile apps. Is there a specific way to structure the code?